# How can I recover / locate non-virtual class methods at run-time?

Tags: disassembly, c++, dynamic-analysis

I know how to find and hook virtual methods by crawling an object's RTTI.  I cannot find enough information about non-virtual class methods.

1. Is there anyway to identify non-virtual class methods at run-time?
2. Can I use a class's symbol name to recover any information about it at run-time?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's no sure-proof way to do it. Non-virtual methods look exactly like normal functions except they take an implicit 'this' pointer. If you are dealing with visual C++ compiled program then it will probably be a bit more obvious as usually it uses **thiscall** calling convention so you just need to watch for cases when the instance address is in ecx at function entry. See [my article](http://www.openrce.org/articles/full_view/23) for more details.

Of course, if you have symbols then it's very easy - just check for `classname::` prefix in the demangled function name.